# Traversing Connections through the Facebook C# API

Tags: c#, facebook, api, facebook-c#-sdk

I am attempting to write an application that harvests information from a logged-in Facebook user.  We are using the Facebook C# API (some documentation [here](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Code%20Examples&referringTitle=Documentation)).  Getting the basic user information is easy enough, but the Graph API supports a lot of connections that link their objects to other arrays of things, which are all important for the application I'm writing.  I am unable to find an example on how to traverse these connections on the codeplex site.  Can anyone provide an example?  Normally I would use the site itself but the discussion page outright requests that question askers use Stack!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample code on how to use the feeds connection.

```
var fb = new FacebookClient("access_token");
dynamic result = fb.Get("/me/feeds");
```

Comment: Appreciate it, that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify much about your application. If this is more of an IT thing than a true "Facebook Application", you could automate using PowerShell with Facebook PS Module.